# BibLaTeX adds incorrect letter after year in incollection entry

Tags: biblatex, biber

i'm facing a problem with my modified authoryear-icomp style.
See screenshot below:
[image: biblatexproblem]

BibLaTeX adds a letter after the year (2017b), even though it's the only publication with that editor in that particular year. Is there any way to circumvent this?
I want it to display like so:

> Krajewski, C. (2017b): „Städtetourismus und Stadtkultur“. In: Heineberg, H. (Hrsg.) (2017): Stadtgeographie. 5. Aufl. Paderborn, S. 413–421 (=UTB 2166).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@article{KrajewskiMetropoleRuhrWandel2017,
  langid = {german},
  title = {Metropole Ruhr – Wandel durch Freizeit, Kultur und Tourismus},
  number = {2},
  journaltitle = {Praxis Geographie},
  author = {Krajewski, Christian},
  date = {2017},
  pages = {36--41}
}

@incollection{KrajewskiStadtetourismusundStadtkultur2017,
  langid = {german},
  location = {{Paderborn}},
  edition = {5},
  title = {Städtetourismus und Stadtkultur},
  isbn = {978-3-8252-4708-9},
  number = {2166},
  booktitle = {Stadtgeographie},
  series = {UTB},
  author = {Krajewski, Christian},
  editor = {Heineberg, Heinz},
  date = {2017-10-10},
  pages = {413--421}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    autopunct=true,
    giveninits=true,
    uniquename=mininit,
    maxcitenames=2,
    maxbibnames=10,
    isbn=false,
    % url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    dashed=false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% colon after year
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

% editor in parentheses
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% no comma before editor
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\printnames{editor}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  \usebibmacro{date+extrayear}}

% change order of incollection
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{editor+others}% %instead of byeditor+others
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


% Series & number at the end in parentheses
\renewbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \printtext{=\addnbthinspace}%
       \printfield{series}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \printfield{number}%
       \newunit}}}

\newcommand*\patchseries[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {}
    {\typeout{Warning: Failed to remove series+number from driver #1.}}
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
    {\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}
    {\typeout{Warning: Failed to add series+number to driver #1.}}}

\patchseries{collection}\patchseries{incollection}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, the labelyear is disambiguated according to the author/editor which is being referred to (the same that will appear in cite commands), in this case Krajewski. And there are indeed two Krajewski's works in 2017 in your bibliography, thus the 'a'/'b'.

Comment: Still, the labeyear is called by your redefinition of the driver for `incollection`, in particular the line `\usebibmacro{editor+others}% %instead of byeditor+others`. That means you do need the date there, but don't want it to receive the "extrayear" part. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, I want the date after Heineberg, H. but without the extrayear part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `extrayear` is called by your redefinition of the driver for incollection, in particular by the line:

```
\usebibmacro{editor+others}% %instead of byeditor+others
```

By substituting it with:

```
\printnames{editor}%
\setunit{\space}%
\usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
\setunit{\space}%
\printfield[parens]{labelyear}%
```

in your bibliography driver for `incollection` you can get the desired result.

[image]

Comment: But using this approach I get “In: Hrsg. von” instead “(Hrsg.)” after the editor. This was the reason I replaced `byeditor+others` with `editor+others` in the first place.
https://s1.postimg.org/1x4mje9c9r/biblatexproblem2.png

Comment: @schmattes Well, I had thought of that as a bonus, for then your `incollection` would receive homogeneous treatment with other similar entrytypes, such as `inbook`. But, once it seems that is what you really want, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use `inbook`very rarely so i can live with that.